# 'body' not accessible in Express router post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm using Express router functions to handle some POST requests.

**Client.js**

```
let data = {
  endpoint: "Blah Blah";
};

return fetch('/api/get-preferences/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

class HTTPServer {
    constructor(credentials, app) {
        this.app = app;
        this.specifyRoutes();
    }

    specifyRoutes() {
        this.router = express.Router();
        this.router.use((req, res, next) => this.jwtVerify(req, res, next));
        this.app.use('/api', this.router);
        this.router.post('/get-preferences', this.getPref);
    }

    jwtVerify(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.body);  // This prints "undefined".
      next();
    }
}
```

I can't access the data that I sent from the client side on the server side in the `jwtVerify` function and once this is fixed, I would like to pass that data to the `getPref` function in the `/get-preferences` route.

Comment: What is `this.app.use('/api', this.router(req, res))` supposed to do?

Comment: @robertklep actually I have few more statements after the `this.app.use('/api', this.router(req, res));` statement. So, it just checks the route for `/api/` and forwards it to the statements below it.

Comment: So where are `req` and `res` coming from? Also, what is `this`?

Comment: I've updated my code to show the use of `this`.

Comment: And the `req` and `res` are the default `request` and `response` parameters.
The `req` parameter is supposed to contain the data sent from the client side in the `body`.

Comment: That particular code should throw a `ReferenceError` because both `req` and `res` are not defined. It's also not clear what `this.app` is (I _assume_ it's the Express instance, but you're not showing the code how everything ties up together).

Comment: I've added some more code. Please have a look at it.
Also, `req` doesn't show any `ReferenceError`. I have tried printing it to console and it prints without any error, but I still can't find my data in it.

Comment: When I try to instantiate `HTTPServer`, an error is thrown on this line: `this.app.use('/api', this.router(req, res))` (because `req` and `res` are undefined, as already stated).

Comment: Although this doesn't display any error on my side (I don't know why), but even if I remove it, I can still print `req` in the `jwtVerify` function.

Comment: Because inside `jwtVerify` it's not undefined. And I can't help you, because the code that you're showing doesn't work for me. I can't even start to possibly reproduce the issue that you have because of that.

Comment: But then why doesn't it print the body of `req` in `jwtVerify`?
And about the code, actually it's very long. But if you can take a look at it, it'd be really helpful- https://github.com/AliceO2Group/ControlGui/blob/master/http/server.js

Comment: And where is `body-parser` being used in that code? Also, the _actual_ code is different from what you're posting in your question...

Comment: I just shared this repository code to give you an idea of the flow. I wrote some code on my own for this project and now I'm trying to merge my code with this. So, I added all the things, that are mentioned in the code shared above. Also, my code worked perfectly when run separately.

Comment: Hopefully someone else will be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here. First, update:

```
this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Second:

```
this.app.use('/api', this.router);
```

Comment: Actually, `app.use(bodyParser.json());` is not in the same class as the routes. It is global.

Comment: And I updated the second one and it still displays undefined when I print the body of request.

Comment: @AnirudhGoel show me, how you create instance of class HTTPServer.

Comment: I have added some code. Do you still need something more?